# AngularJs promise not refreshing after data update

Tags: jquery, angularjs, mongodb

I need update a document  using angular and mongodb.

The update function("vm.UpdateItem") is working well.

My problem is how to refresh the view after the update.

To do it, I click a button and call a promise in "vm.UpdateItem()" to update the document.
When the promise returns I can check the  returned data were updated.

After that, I reload the data from server with "loadFilaLists" function, but the data  is not showing updated.

If I hit CTRL-F5, the view reloads and shows correctly the data just updated.

I can´t see where is the error, because, I am using the "then" from promise correctly.

Is there a timer problem in some place.

Is ok update a mongodb document and read back it immediatelly, or is there some "timeouts" limits to do it?

Some help will be appreciated.

//markup

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ng-click="vm.UpdateItem()">
 <span>Update Item</span>
</button>
```

//service

```
 angular.module("clinang").service('dataService', ['$http','config', function ($http,config) {
       this.postFilas = function (cond) {
            return $http.post(urlBase + '/filas/all', cond)
        };

        this.getFilas = function (where) {
            return $http.get(urlBase+'/filas',{params:{"where":where}});
        };

        this.getFila = function (id) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/filas/' + id);
        };
        this.insertFila = function (tipo) {
            return $http.post(urlBase+'/filas', tipo);
        };

        this.updateFila = function (tipo) {
            return $http.post(urlBase + '/filas/' + tipo._id, tipo)
        };        

        this.deleteFila = function (id) {
            return $http.delete(urlBase+'/filas/' + id);
        };
}]);
```

//controller

```
var postFilas=function(checked, di, df){
         var deferred=$q.defer()
         var cond=checked?medId:undefined;
         var obj={'profissional':cond, '$and':[
               {'datahora_ent':{'$gte':di}}, 
               {'datahora_ent':{'$lt': df}} 
             ] };
         dataService.postFilas(obj).then( (response)=>{
           deferred.resolve(response.data) 
         })
         .catch( (erro)=>{
             deferred.reject('erro') 
         })

         return deferred.promise
    }

 var loadFilaLists=function(checked){
         var di=moment(vm.dateRange.date.startDate).clone().startOf('day').toDate();
         var df=moment(vm.dateRange.date.endDate).clone().endOf('day').toDate();
         postFilas(checked,di,df).then( (data)=>{
           console.log('data2',data) //problem - data is showing old data, before the update
         })
  }

vm.UpdateItem=function(item){
          dataService.updateFila(item).then( (response)=>{  //updated
              console.log('data1',response.data) //data is updated and return ok 
              loadFilaLists(true); //trying refresh all data
           }
  }
loadFilaLists(true)
```

Comment: I think your post API is returning old data from the server side.

Comment: No, it is not.  If I put "loadFilaLists" function into a $timeout(function(){loadFilaLists},1000) the problem is over. Why I can´t update a document and read back immediatelly the document just updated?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you only just need to add `$promise` in your service,

```
this.postFilas = function (cond) {
    return $http.post(urlBase + '/filas/all', cond).$promise;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but $http already return a promise. If I put "loadFilaLists" function into a $timeout(function(){loadFilaLists},1000) the problem is over. Why I can´t update a document and read back immediatelly?

Comment: Sorry I just solved it. It was a problem in my remote server